# bat: recursive rename files

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd.exe

I would like to recursively rename all *.doc files in a certain partition to *.txt. I have tried the following without success...

```
@echo off
echo +-------------------------------------------+
echo :         exec cmd in every subdir          :
echo +-------------------------------------------+

FOR /R ".\" %%F IN (.) DO (
    ren "*.doc" "*.txt"
)

@pause
```

what am I doing wrong?

---

**Update: This worked for me...**
I am running this by clicking on the file in MS File Explorer (Win7) and have .bat set as a executable. I did not try at a cmd prompt - I wonder if this causes a difference?

```
@echo off

FOR /R ".\" %%F IN (.) DO (
 ren "%%F\*.doc" "*.txt"
)
@pause
```

Comment: Can you clarify the actual question? Are you trying to get this to work under real MS-DOS?

Comment: MS-DOS doesn't have for /R http://www.vfrazee.com/ms-dos/6.22/help/for.htm

Comment: a good queston would be why doesn't it work in Windows  https://pastebin.com/raw/pHHJtmby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several small errors in the batch file.

Here is a version that works from the command line:

```
FOR /R "." %F IN (.) DO ren "%F\*.doc" "*.txt"
```

And in a `.bat` file:

```
FOR /R "." %%F IN (.) DO ren "%%F\*.doc" "*.txt"
```

Tested on Windows 7 64-bit:

[image]

Comment: This still does not work in win7 :(

Comment: Worked for me (Windows 10 but batch is the same). Add to your post a screenshot of the problem so we can understand it.

Comment: There is nothing to show, it errors and immediately closes the window in a split second. The command window is not the same in Win7 and Win10; MS re-wrote it :(

Comment: I tested on Windows 7 and it still works. You have some subtle error - try to run the `.bat` file from CMD to better see the error.

Comment: This eventualy worked for me note the use of %%F   
FOR /R ".\" %%F IN (.) DO (
 ren "%%F\*.doc" "*.txt"
)

Comment: Also I am running this by clicking on the file in file explorer and have .bat set as a executable. I did not try at a cmd prompt - I wonder if this causes a difference?

Comment: Sorry about that error. My `test.bat` file did indeed have `%%F` but I didn't notice it was missing in my answer. Fixed now.